# How to prove figure eight is not a manifold?

Tags: manifolds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A wedge sum of circles without the gluing point is not path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213515/a-wedge-sum-of-circles-without-the-gluing-point-is-not-path-connected)

I know that figure eight is not a manifold because its center has no neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. But how to prove this strictly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose that there was a neighborhood $U$ of the center point $P$ that was homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Consider $U \setminus \{P\}$.  How many connected components does it have?  How many connected components are there in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{\text{point}\}$?  [Be careful to note that the answer is different for $n=1$ than for $n > 1$, but that doesn't ultimately cause any trouble.]

Comment: I got it, but can I assume that $U$ is a small nbd of $P$? Then the connected components will be 4, but if $U$ is strangely shaped, the components can be more than 4.

Comment: @Gobi: $P$ has arbitrarily small $+$-shaped nbhds; no point of $\Bbb R^n$ has such a nbhd. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/213538/12042) and the comments following it.

Comment: Sorry for the necropost. I think is safe to assume if the figure 8 was a manifold, it would be a 1-manifold. But if you remove P, I see just two components: The "North " one and its "South" counterpart. Just as you'd find two connected components in $\mathbb R - \{p\} $